# Could not install or delete a package 12.10

Tags: 12.10

Could not install or uninstall package due to previous configuration issues. 
I tried sudo apt-get -f install. it didn't work. Tried sudo apt-get --purge remove php5-xdebug. No change. Appreciate any help.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
php5-xdebug is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up php5-xdebug (2.2.1-1) ...
ERROR: /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini does not exist
dpkg: error processing php5-xdebug (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php-codecoverage:
php-codecoverage depends on php5-xdebug; however:
Package php5-xdebug is not configured yet.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make by `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` hand, and then purge the package and then `sudo apt-get -f install`. Hope to work properly for you.